# Crispr/CAS9 genome editing is actually processed at which phase of Cell cycle?

Tags: crispr, cell-cycle

all,

Is it only happens in certain phases, like S, G1,...or it can happen any time....or maybe, it has some perferences.

Put it in another word, does it going to processe edit if the cell is not growing ?

Thanks for any helps or comments.

Best

Bill Zhang